# Does more MySQL user will require more CPU & memory usage?

Tags: mysql

Usually I will make 1 MySQL user for every database, instead 1 MySQL user for all database.

but I just wonder.. does more MySQL user will require more CPU & memory usage?

Answer (score 3):

Simply put NO..

The amount of users is not comparable to memory or cpu..

In fact, to get to the point..

It is the amount of connections ( which use MEMORY )
and
What those connections are doing ( Which use CPU )

Usually a connection/thread is capable of maximising 1 cpu core

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

More Memory: Yes, though not in a relevant area.

More CPU: similar.

Multiple logins, multiple open connections e tc. - but at the end not in a range that is relevant compared to query processing and caching. I actually doubt you will be able to measure the higher use outside of lab scenarios (hundreds or thousands of users with no real load) designed to measure exactly this.